# Disable show all windows when pressing winkey + arrow

Tags: windows-10

When I'm pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>, the open window is pushed to one half of the screen and in the other side I get a view of all other windows (and I can choose one of them to open it in that half of the screen).

Is there a way to cancel this window grouping?

I'd just love the window to be pushed to one side and for nothing else to happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the option in the following steps:

Settings -> System -> Multitasking -> Under the **Snap** section **Off** the "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it" option.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Settings]

Comment: With 1909 the sliders (except the first) where replaced by checkboxes but nothing relevant was changed